# Pass JavaScript split() function to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a binding expression that uses JavaScript split() method in obtaining values in a string. For example `{{ failureDetail.name.split('#')[0]}}`. This will return merchantId (the 0th index of # separated string is merchantId). This works fine. When I attempt to pass this value to **ng-model** directive, it doesn't work. The purpose here is to do a filtering based on merchantId. The problem seems is, **split()** function does not work inside ng-model directive. 
What is the recommended way of doing this.The code is below.

```
 <tr ng-repeat-start="failureDetail in failureDetails | filterByTags:tags | filter:merchantStatus">
                          <td>
                             <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-if="failureDetail.expanded" ng-click="failureDetail.expanded = false"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
                             <button class="btn btn-success" ng-if="!failureDetail.expanded" ng-click="failureDetail.expanded = true"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
                          </td>
                          <td title="ID" filter="{ failureDetail.name.split('#')[0]: 'text'}" sortable="'failureDetail.name.split('#')[0]'" >{{failureDetail.name.split('#')[0]}}</td>
                          <td title="Name" filter="{failureDetail.name.split('#')[1] : 'text'}" sortable="'failureDetail.name.split('#')[1]'">{{failureDetail.name.split('#')[1]}}</td>
                          <td title="AB" filter="{failureDetail.name.split('#')[4] : 'text'}" sortable="'failureDetail.name.split('#')[4]'">{{failureDetail.name.split('#')[4]}}</td>
                          <!--<td>{{failureDetail.name.split('#')[2]}}</td
                            <td title="'ID'" filter="{ ID: 'text'}" sortable="'ID'">
                          >-->
                          <td title="CD" filter="{failureDetail.name.split('#')[3] : 'text'}" sortable="'failureDetail.name.split('#')[3]'">{{failureDetail.name.split('#')[3]}}</td>

                       </tr>
```

Comment: You need prepare an array before iterate it with `ng-repeat`. For example `angular.each($scope.failureDetails,function(item){item.id =item.name.split('#')[0] ... and so on })`. Then in template use `<td title="ID" filter="{ failureDetail.name.id: 'text'}" sortable="'failureDetail.name.id'" >{{failureDetail.name.id}}</td>`;

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the `merchandId` in your controller variable:

```
$scope.merchantId = $scope.failureDetail.name.split('#')[0]
```

Then, you will be able to do what you want: `ng-model="merchantId"`

Hope it helps

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. the failureDetail comes via ng-repeat directive. [ng-repeat failureDetail in failuresDetail]

Comment: can you post the code of what you are doing with `ng-model` and `ng-repeat`?

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is to make table filtering for every column. So basically under each column, there will be input tag that includes ng-model to achieve this. Table results are populated via ng-repeat-start.

Comment: I think I understand your problem, but showing your js code would help.  I'm assuming failureDetails is an delimited array?